# Struggling to configure nodemailer to use gmail with oAuth2

Tags: javascript, typescript, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I've followed [this tutorial](https://alexb72.medium.com/how-to-send-emails-using-a-nodemailer-gmail-and-oauth2-fe19d66451f9) to get nodemailer set up using gmail.

My transporter is configured as follows:

```js
const transportObj = {
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    type: "OAuth2",
    user: "myemail@gmail.com",
    clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    clientSecret: "xxxxxxxx",
    refreshToken: "xxxxxxxxx",
    accessToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
};
```

However, when

```js
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transportObj);
```

is called, i get the error

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ host: string; port: number; secure: boolean; auth: { type: string; user: string; serviceClient: string; privateKey: string; accessToken: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Transport | TransportOptions'.
      Type '{ host: string; port: number; secure: boolean; auth: { type: string; user: string; serviceClient: string; privateKey: string; accessToken: string; }; }' has no properties in common with type 'TransportOptions'.

467         transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transportObj);
```

My transport object seems to match the examples in the [nodemailer documentation](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/), so I'm not sure what else to try.

Note: This is being used with firebase cloud functions. Could that be causing the issue?

Answer (score 7):

Solved by changing import statement from

```js
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
```

to

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```